# React Native can't upload image to API (Problem with Content-Type & The File Field is required). 2d stuck on it :(

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios, react-native-image-picker

I've try some solution on stackoverflow about this problem but there is no way out. This is my error on debugger :
[RED = Image File Details | BLUE = Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O5hd.png)

Im using react-native-image-picker and axios on this case. There is my code on sign up (to call API for register user)

```
const API_HOST = {
  url: 'http://skripsibackend.test:8081/api',
};

export const signUpAction =
  (dataRegister, photoReducer, navigation) => dispatch => {
    Axios.post(`${API_HOST.url}/register`, dataRegister)
      .then(res => {
        console.log('data success: ', res.data);

        if (photoReducer.isUploadPhoto) {
          const photoForUpload = new FormData();
          photoForUpload.append('files', photoReducer);

          Axios.post(`${API_HOST.url}/user/photo`, photoForUpload, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `${res.data.data.token_type} ${res.data.data.access_token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
          })
            .then(resUpload => {
              console.log('success upload: ', resUpload);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              showMessage('Photo Upload Failed ');
              console.log('image failed: ', error.response);
            });
        } else {
          () => {};
        }
        dispatch(setLoading(false));
        showMessage('Register Success', 'success');
        navigation.replace('SignUpSuccess');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch(setLoading(false));
        console.log('sign up error: ', err.response);
        showMessage('Error Sign Up');
      }); 
};
```

then, this is my photoReducer code :

```
export const photoReducer = (state = initPhoto, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'SET_PHOTO') {
    return {
      ...state,
      uri: action.value.uri,
      type: action.value.type,
      name: action.value.name,
    };
  }
  if (action.type === 'SET_UPLOAD_STATUS') {
    return {
      ...state,
      isUploadPhoto: action.value,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

> I've try to remove multipart/form-data from content-type, so it can
> remove the error about "Missing Boundary in multipart/form-data".
> Yeah, it can remove that error but stil came another error, that is
> "The File field is required".

> As u can see on my error image from debugger, on the RED LINE it was
> the information about the picture I've upload.

I've test the API to upload photo using postman, and it works. so I think there is no problem on my API. I've stuck for 2 days on this error. Any idea for this one? :)

Comment: Your signUpAction function seems right... I think your problem is in photoReducer. 
Have you tried to create a state (without Redux) for the image object and tried to send it?

Comment: nice idea, let me check if it works without Redux